# Trouble with "import sys import argv"

Tags: python

I have read the chapters over and over in the Python the hard way book and no matter what I do or how much I have reread it and researched it. I can't find anything to explain this error:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '**

print(f"Hi {user_name}?")
print("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")
print(f"Do you like me {user_name}?")
likes = input(prompt)

print(f"Where do you live {user_name}?")
lives = input(prompt)

print(f'What kind of computer do you have?')

computer = input(prompt)

print(f""" 
Alright, so you said {likes} about liking me.
You live in {lives}. Not sure where that is.
and you have a {computer} computer. Nice.
""")
```

Error I keep getting:

```
PS C:\Users\Rich Mazel\Desktop\Python\lpthw> python test15.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test15.py", line 2, in <module> script, user_name = argv 
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I have literally started 3 days ago and have finally got stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to unpack the args you pass in to the `test15.py` script into `script, user_name`. So when you call it, make sure to actually call it *with the username*.

Calling `python test15.py some_username` from your shell should at least get you past the unpacking `ValueError`.

P.S. Consider using `argparse` instead of `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0):

So that means you don't have two values for `argv`, so?

You just can't do this.

Unless you run it on the command line

```
python file_including_code.py foo
Hi foo.py?
I'd like to ask you a few questions.
Do you like me foo?
> **Yes
Where do you live foo?
> **earth
What kind of computer do you have?
> **Windows

Alright, so you said Yes about liking me.
You live in earth. Not sure where that is.
and you have a Windows computer. Nice.
```

Comment: @SFM99 Edited mine